# Base rate calculation for customer conversion

Tags: classification, statistical-significance, naive-bayes, churn

Question: What is the base rate of conversion for mobile versus desktop sites?

Total no of customers: 590381 Out of 590381, the Total no of customers that were converted: 701

These customers used mobile or desktop sites

Total no of customers using mobile: 269400 No of customers that were converted using mobile: 507

Total no of customers using the desktop site: 320981 No of customers converted using the desktop site: 194

What is the base rate of conversion for mobile versus desktop sites?

Comment: Does this relate to class exercise? If yes, please see https://stats.stackexchange.com/tags/self-study/info and add the tag to modify the question accordingly